# Using parent constructor instead of defining child

Tags: c++

I have a base class `Foo` and two child classes `Bar` and `Car`. `Foo` is pure virtual. `Bar` inherits foo with its own constructor to assign a variable. However `Car` doesn't have a constructor.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
class Foo{
public:
    virtual void T() = 0;
};
class Bar : public Foo{
protected:
    int n;
public:
    Bar(int n){
        this->n = n;
    }
    virtual void T(){
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
};
class Car : public Bar{
    void T(){
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Foo* f = new Car(10);//error
    return 0;
}
```

What I'd like to do essentially, is instantiate `new Car` but instead of writing out the constructor for `Car` and then calling the parents constructor

```
    Car(int n) : Bar(n){
        
    }
```

It would be so much easier if by instantiate car, because a constructor isn't explicitly defined it automatically calls the parent's constructor?

Is that possible?

Comment: Re: "`Foo` is pure virtual." No, it's an **abstract class** because it has at least one **pure virtual function**.

Comment: @PeteBecker What would make it pure virtual?

Comment: There is no such thing as a pure virtual class. There are pure virtual functions and there are abstract classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [inheriting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) as:

```
class Car : public Bar {
    using Bar::Bar;
    ...
};
```

Then

```
Car car(10); // Bar base subobject is initialized by Bar(10)
```